Strange locust behavior in extreme cases
I am working on a Ubuntu desktop and try to run  load testing to check  our server sites capacity.  Usually my load testing is of  500 to 2000 users with the time range of 4 to 12 hours.  And everything runs smoothly before it ends on time.
Today, I was trying to see how the server site behaves, in some extreme case. So I have it executed with 10000 users for testing in 10 minutes, ramp-up rate is 1000.
Here is my running command:
locust -f locustTesting.py --host=http://server.site -u 10000 -t 10m -r 1000 --html testing.html .
a) locustTesting.py is my test script, that contains a list of subsequent API calls.
b) testing.html would be the test results.
As of now,  I have seen such diagram from http://127.0.0.1:8089 site.

As you may find:

it is 80 minutes passed the starting time, and the locust script is still on-going !
10 minutes later, the number has dropped from 10000 to about 100, on this bottom user chart.

So my questions are:

What happen 10 minutes after ? Are they suppose to be stop by then ?
If I did receive my "testing.html" in the end, is that the data contains the full-run, or just the first 10 minutes?
In order to get the this  testing.html file, I have to keep waiting, right ?

Thanks for the tips.
Jack

Hi Jack! Start by updating to the latest version of Locust. I'm not sure which version you are on but it hasn't looked like that for a while :)

Thanks. I have upgraded to the last locust and I no longer see this issue.

I was using locust of version 2.20.1. Thanks to
Cyberwiz's suggestion, I have upgraded to 2.30.1, and I no longer see this issue.
problem solved.
